# How do you know what a korean word says in english when reading it

Tags: grammar

What I mean by this is that I know how to read korean but I dont understand what it actually says or what it says in english. I need help

Comment: When you say " I know how to read Korean", do you mean that you know what sounds are written ? Out of interest, how did you learn that?

Comment: Yes I know what the sound is but not what it means, by remembering hangeul

Comment: The way you know it is by memorizing the word, the same way you do for any other new word you want to learn. Or use a Korean-to-English dictionary

Comment: I plan on buying books for learning like grammar and vocabulary. But what am I exactly supposed to learn if I can read the sounds of the korean sentence but have no clue what it says

Comment: @KrissueNi once you know the vocabulary, you will know what each word means; once you know the grammar, you will understand how the words relate to each other to form statements and questions. Is this your first time learning a foreign language?

Comment: Yes it is my first time learning a different language

Comment: I laughed so hard when I read your question because my thoughts exactly. I'm like well I know all my symbols and how to pronounce them but I have no idea what I just said. I guess it's just like when you learn any language you can read it all you want but if you don't know the word you don't know what you saying. How frustrating lol

Answer (score 6):

The answer is simple, you need to learn Korean (not only know how to read Korean alphabet/hangeul, but also know how to use Korean grammar and structure).

You also need to enrich your vocabulary. Most of the time, you will most likely be able to know (at least, guess) what Korean people say if you know the meaning of the words they use, even though you have yet to know the grammar.

If you don't have enough time/money to look for a course to learn Korean, you can learn it online. Unlike Chinese, there are plenty of websites that give you lessons about Korean language for free. Don't worry, they provide basic until advanced level of Korean. So, you will be able to learn from the most basic ones to the advanced ones ^___^
One of the most popular websites to learn Korean is Talk To Me in Korean because they provide free pdf to each lesson. If you are not someone who likes learning online, you can print their pdf and start learning Korean.

---

Plus, please note that it takes quite a great amount of time (well, at least for me) to fully understand a language. You can't expect to be fluent only in days or months of learning.
I'm not referring this part to you, but to those who like to complain about not being fluent only after several weeks/months of learning.

---

Written by someone who's majoring in Korean Language